# Preventing ghost click when binding 'touchstart' and 'click'

Tags: jquery, mobile

I'm developing an app, testing on my desktop and mobile. I am trying to fix these slow button presses on the mobile, and just learned about the difference between touchstart and click.

So I bound my buttons with jquery to perform both touchstart and click like so:

```
$('.button').on('touchstart click', function(){
});
```

Now the app is performing slightly better on the phone. However, it is performing a touch click, and then a regular click, ie potentially double clicks, or when the next slide comes in, it clicks on something there. In my case a form is appearing, and the input field that appears in the space where the button clicked was, is selected. Ghost click.

How can I tell my function that if there is a touch, ignore the click?

Or better yet, is there a way to tell jquery to just acknowledge all 'clicks' as touches?

I would remove the 'click' binding, but then I can't exactly test in my desktop environment so easily.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to do specific stuff for different event types use `e.type`

```
$('.button').on('touchstart click', function(e) {    
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent default behavior
    if(e.type == "touchstart") {
        // Handle touchstart event.
    } else if(e.type == "click") {
        // Handle click event.
    }
});
```

Comment: This does not prevent the click event from firing in Firefox (only one I've tested so far).

It simply does both, and if you want the same behavior in mobile as in a desktop browser, it *still* executes that action twice.

Comment: Please notice - this solution does not work on Samsung browsers (so inside a Webview for devices with OS version lower than 4.4 it will trigger both events)

Comment: `e.stopPropagation()` does not prevent the second event from being fired. `e.preventDefault()` will do the trick though.

Comment: How is `e.stopPropagation()` going to stop 2nd event? It, as well as `e.preventDefault()`, is working on the current event only, and here we'll have 2 independent events.

Answer (score 12):

Touchstart should happen before click, so I remove the click handler if the event is of type touchstart.  This seems to be working nicely for my purposes:

```
$('.do-popdown').on('click touchstart', handlePopdown);
function handlePopdown(e){
    if(e.type == 'touchstart') {
        $('.do-popdown').off('click', handlePopdown).click(function(e){
            // do nothing
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
    }
    // do my handling...
    // and nothing else:
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

The `e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault(); return false;` may be overkill, but I use this on a variety of different elements (`<a>`, `<div>`, `<span>`, `<button>`, &c.) and this meets my usual needs.

**EDIT:** A more general (better?) approach is to create something similar to the familiar `.click()` event binder:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    clickOrTouch: function(handler) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var event = ('ontouchstart' in document) ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
            $(this).on(event, handler);
        });
    }
});
```

This way, only the appropriate event is attached to the selected element(s).

I suppose a more "proper" name would be `.touchstartOrClick()` but since it is more or less a replacement for `.click()` I decided to start the name with `click`.

This can be used just like `.click()`. For example, put a `button` inside of a `div` and run:

```
$('button').clickOrTouch(doSomething);
$('div').clickOrTouch(doSomething);
function doSomething(e) {
    $('body').append(this.tagName + ' ' + e.type + '<br>');
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

This will show "DIV click" or "BUTTON touchstart" depending on how it is triggered. If this is used on a link, add `e.preventDefault()` if needed in your handler.

Comment: At first glance, it looks good!  I'll have to give this a try sometime.  I actually kind of abandoned the road I was going down, but I'll be back for this, undoubtedly.

Comment: Note that with devices having things like both mouse and touch events, just detecting the touch events on a device aren't enough, and unbinding click events because of a touch could disable mouse clicks.

Comment: You should never attach handler for `touchstart` OR `click` as some devices will have both: one for when touchscreen is used, another for when mouse/trackpad is used.

Answer (score 4):

This code from @Krishna doesn't work for me:

```
$('.button').on('touchstart click', function(e) {    
    e.stopPropagation(); //stops propagation
    if(e.type == "touchstart") {
        // Handle touchstart event.
    } else if(e.type == "click") {
        // Handle click event.
    }
});
```

But this one should work, as @Slashback originally suggested.

```
$('.button').on('touchstart click', function(e) {    
    e.preventDefault();

    if(e.type == "touchstart") {
        // Handle touchstart event.
    } else if(e.type == "click") {
        // Handle click event.
    }
});
```

.preventDefault() alone worked for me instead of .stopPropagation(). I din't have to do the overkill as well.

Comment: This seems more of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using PhoneGap. This maybe helpful:

```
function longTapEvent(id, longTapFun) {
    $(id).click(function() {
        longTapFun();
        return;
    })

    $(id).unbind("touchstart");
    $(id).bind("touchstart", function() {
        //do sth...
    });
    $(id).unbind("touchend");
    $(id).bind("touchend", function() {
        //do sth...
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can detect click and escape the current firing of the function if the previous fire was not a click (i.e. was a touch or something else) - in vanilla js:

```
buttonx.addEventListener('touchend',clicktap);
buttonx.addEventListener('click',clicktap);

function clicktap(e) {
var c = e.type.includes("click"); // or "mouse" if using "mousedown"
if (c && (this.wastouched)) return this.wastouched = 0;
this.wastouched = !c;

// ..run things..

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my own home brewed solution, please critique the hell out of it! thanks!

Basically, if you click the price button, the item is immediately added to cart.

If you tap/touchpress the button, it shows the price.
Tap/touchpress it the second time, item is added to cart.

See it in action here: https://www.indospace.io/studio-city/urban-treez

```
    var price_button = $(evt.target).closest('.price-button')
    if(price_button.length) {
        price_button.on('mouseleave', function() {
            $(this).removeAttr('data-touched')
        })
        if(evt.type == 'touchstart') {
            jQuery.touch_start = true
            if(!price_button.attr('data-touched')) {
                price_button.attr('data-touched', 1)
                return
            }
            price_button.attr('data-touched', 2)
        }
        if(evt.type == 'click') {
            if(price_button.attr('data-touched'))
                return
        }
        bag.add(price_button)
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to differentiate user dragging and click, with vanilla JS using **touchmove** instead of `touchstart` works for me:

```
 document.querySelector("#mydiv").addEventListener("click", function(e){
    console.log("click");
 });
 let count = 0;
 document.querySelector("#mydiv").addEventListener("touchmove", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // if need to detect once
    //count++;
    //if(count == 3){
    //  console.log("dragged!");  // dragHandler(), and reset count later
    //}

    console.log("touchmove");
 });
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Supporting_both_TouchEvent_and_MouseEvent

Answer (score -1):

Use of data-tap-disabled="true" on element solve my problem.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/page/tap/

Answer (score -2):

I use the following in my projects:

```
$('.button').on('touchstart', function() {

   var thisButton = $(this); 
   if(!thisButton.hasClass('disabled')) {
     thisButton.addClass('disabled'); //add class disabled to prevent double execution

     ............rest of code

     window.setTimeout(function () {
        thisButton.removeClass('disabled'); //remove class disalbed after 300ms
     }, 300);

});
```

I hope this will help someone.